# SQL query to get list of employees who work in all the projects from a location

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table structure:

- `Employee` (emp_id, emp_name, emp_age)
- `ProjectDetails` (projid, p_name, p_location)
- `EmpLoyeeProject` (emp_no,  project_num, hrs)

For employee to project, the relationship is many-to-many.

Can you please help to write a SQL query to get the `eid` and `ename` for those employees working on all projects located in "OneLocation"?

Comment: located in ? what?

Comment: ina a location like place name like SFO. I mean one location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I properly understood your schema, SQL query could look like:

```
select distinct emp_id, emp_name from Emplyee e
        inner join EmpLoyeeProject ep on ep.emp_no=e.emp_id
        inner join ProjectDetails p on p.projid=ep.project_num
    where p_location=?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_name
    FROM Emplyee e
    INNER JOIN EmpLoyeeProject ep 
    ON e.emp_id = ep.emp_no
    AND ep.project_num IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ep.project_num 
        FROM EmpLoyeeProject epr 
        INNER JOIN ProjectDetails ep
        ON epr.project_num = p.projid
        WHERE p_location = 'OneLocation'
    )
```

Comment: This query shall give all emp working in a location. but will not return employee who work in all the project belonging to a particular location

Answer (score 0):

I think you can retrieve all the employee list involved in the project by using inner join as below:

```
SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_name
FROM Emplyee e
INNER JOIN EmpLoyeeProject ep ON ep.emp_no = e.emp_id
INNER JOIN ProjectDetails pd ON pd.projid = ep.project_num
    AND pd.p_location = 'youLocation'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this as a solution which will also allow you to select multiple locations.

This is the minimum required for your query,

```
SELECT
     e.emp_id
,    e.emp_name
FROM
     employee         e
JOIN employeeproject  ep on e.emp_id = ep.emp_no          -- assuming that ep.emp_no and e.emp_id are the same value (most likely the case)
join projectdetails   pd on ep.projid = pd.project_number -- assuming that these are the same value.
WHERE
    p_location in ('Melbourne') -- set your location , you can also go ('melbourne','sydney','adelaide')
```

However I would expand it out a little to provide a little more data to make it a little bit more meaningful for who ever is asking for the information.

```
SELECT
     e.emp_id
,    e.emp_name
,    pd.p_location
,    p_name
FROM
     employee         e
JOIN employeeproject  ep on e.emp_id = ep.emp_no          -- assuming that ep.emp_no and e.emp_id are the same value (most likely the case)
join projectdetails   pd on ep.projid = pd.project_number -- assuming that these are the same value.
WHERE
    p_location in ('Melbourne') -- set your location , you can also go ('melbourne','sydney','adelaide')
```

If you use a reporting service like SSRS then you can do some cool stuff like passing parameters for you report based off location

You can make things like a drop down box similar to the below to make it even more user friendly (this one is so the user can limit the data to the specific month / months they are wishing to look at.

[image]